# How to do gdb with java -cp myjar.jar class.myclass

Tags: linux, gdb, java

How to tell gdb run this way: `gdb java -cp /var/tmp/Test.jar myjava.class`

```
$ gdb /var/tmp/Test.jar 14940
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2-1ubuntu11) 7.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
"/var/tmp/Test.jar": not in executable format: File format not recognized
Attaching to process 14940
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
/var/tmp/14940: No such file or directory.
(gdb) run
Starting program:  
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
(gdb) 

$ gdb -p 14940
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.2-1ubuntu11) 7.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Attaching to process 14940
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
(gdb) run
Starting program:  
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
(gdb)
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?! Debug the java executable? Or debug the Java program (for which better options exist)?

Comment: @DaveNewton: Debug the Java Executable to share with other Gdb and C debug team, to represent that my Java class is breaking because of there C wrappers has bugs or etc.

Comment: You should be able to attach to the process as per [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rt.doc.10/diag/problem_determination/linux_gdb.html) as one option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From GDB's point of view, the program here is java. It accepts many arguments (-cp , classname etc)

You can set arguments using `set args`

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_19.html